# use alt or title on text

Tags: html, css, title

i want to use title on text. is this possible to make title on text?
on some hard meaning of text i want use title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general text,

```
<span title="By this I mean that...">difficult part</span>
```

For acronyms, you can use

```
The <acronym title="full-width half-maximum">FWHM</acronym> wavelength is...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<p title="Alternate Text">Text</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp